# what is the mistake of my calculation ,Transformation of the \$\Delta\$ to \$Y\$ circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, current, homework

If \$I=4A\$ ,and \$r=6Ω\$,then what is \$R\$?The answer for this is \$R=18Ω\$,but my answer of my calculation is always \$R=36Ω\$.

[image]

**My calculation**

Transform the \$\Delta\$ circuit ,which resistors are all \$RΩ\$ ,to \$Y\$ circuit , and combine it with the other \$Y\$ circuit,which resistors are all \$r=6Ω\$,and the circuit will become this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuVwu1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So the resistance for this circuit will become

\$R_{th}=(6|| \frac{R}{3})+[(6|| \frac{R}{3})||(6|| \frac{R}{3})]=\frac{6R}{18+R}+\frac{3R}{18+R}=\frac{9R}{18+R}\$

So \$I=\frac{V}{R}\$.that is \$4=\frac{24}{\frac{9R}{18+R}}\$ ,so \$R=36Ω\$.what is the mistake of my calculation,can anyone tell me??

Comment: Who says you have made a mistake? What is the correct answer?

Comment: R=18Ω is the correct answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be clear that the leftmost R is connected directly between 24+ and 24-.

Try starting from here:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fETxma.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Schematic redrawn.*

Hint: what is the voltage across r3?

Your answer of 18 Ω is correct.

Comment: thx a lot,i never think this method before

Answer (score 1):

I think I have a mentally simpler way to calculate the problem, than yours. At least I find it more intuitive to break down the problem to smaller chunks by manipulating the circuit. It involves less equation cracking and I believe it provides more insight. At least for me. That's why I would rather share my way, than finding the errors in your calculation.

I would first convert the star structure to a delta one. Than you have two delta structures in parallel. I will calculate the effective resistance and the current through these structures to get the value of R.

Due to the same value of all resistance in the delta shape, it is easy to calculate the effective resistance between two points: $$ R_e = R || 2R = \frac 2 3 R \, .$$

The star to delta formaulas are easily available, for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-%CE%94_transform

With that, the delta equivalent of the star shape is r`=3r, and its resistance betwen two points are 2r, i.e. 12 Ω, therefore the current through it is 24V/12 Ω =2A. This leaves 2A for the R structure. Using the equation above we get
$$ \frac 2 3 R \cdot 2A = 24V$$
Which results R=18 Ω.